# Use contour integration to calculate $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2+a^2}dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration, complex-integration

> Use contour integration to calculate the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2+a^2}dx$ with $a>0$

For this I have a solution (where they expand $\sin^2(x) = \frac{1}{2}(1-\cos(2x))$ and then put $\sin^2(x) = \frac{1}{2}\Re(1-e^{2it})$. But when I first attempted it I tried it with the function $$f(z) = \frac{\sin^2(z)}{z^2+a^2}.$$

I know that the poles are $+ia,-ia$. Consider a contour integral which is a halfcircle on the upperhalf plane, $\gamma_R = [-R,R] \cup C_R$.

With the residue formula $\int_{\gamma_R}f(z) dz$ gives me $\frac{\pi}{a}(\sinh(a))^2$.

But I'm having troubles with getting $\int_{C_R} f(z)dz \leq 0$.
I first tried this
\begin{align}
\big|\int_{C_R} f(z)dz\big| &\leq \int_{C_R}\big|\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2+a^2}\big|dz\\
&\leq \int_{C_R}\big|\frac{1}{x^2+a^2}\big|dz
\end{align}

But apparently $sin(z)\nleq 1$ for $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

My question is, is it possible to find an estimate with this complex function so that I can get $\int_{C_R} f(z)dz \leq 0$? Or do I have to use the formula $\sin^2(x) = \frac{1}{2}(1-\cos(2x))$?

Comment: Indeed the choice of $\sin(z)$ won't work because its an entire function and its not bounded in the semi circular path that increases its radius. You should use the trig identity and then use an exponential complex function.

Comment: Okay thank you. Do you maybe have advice on how to know when I have to use trigonometric identities because I'm a bit stuck?

Comment: Better: replace $\frac12(1-\cos2x)$ with $\frac12(1-e^{2ix})$, then take the real part of the integral.

Comment: @fieke_2000 if your integrand is of the form $R(x)\; \sin(ax)$ or $R(x) \; \cos(ax)$, where $R(x)$ is a rational function, you will need to use the complex function $R(z) \; e^{iaz}$, then take real and imaginary parts. If the trig function appears in a power, you deffinetly need to use a trig identity.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you so much!